# How to avoid memory leaks when using Base64 images in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, blazor, maui

I am using the official version of .NET 8 for developing a Blazor MAUI hybrid app.
I have a feature where the user can select an image and it is displayed to the user. I am using Base64, but I have noticed a memory leak. Here is my code:

```
@page "/memory_leak"
@using System.Diagnostics

<MudStack Class="ma-4" AlignItems="AlignItems.Center">
    <MudPaper Class="pa-3" Elevation="3">
        @if (_imageBase64 is null)
        {
            <MudAlert Severity="Severity.Normal">Choose an Image</MudAlert>
        }
        else
        {
            <MudImage Height="400" Alt="pic" Class="rounded-lg" 
                      Src="@string.Concat("data:image/png;base64,", _imageBase64)" 
                      />
        }
    </MudPaper>
    <MudFileUpload T="IBrowserFile" FilesChanged="UploadFiles" Class="pa-3">
            <ButtonTemplate>
                <MudFab
                    Size="Size.Small"
                    HtmlTag="label"
                        Color="Color.Secondary"
                        Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Image"
                        Label="Load picture"
                        for="@context" />
            </ButtonTemplate>
        </MudFileUpload>
    <MudPaper Class="pa-3">Item 3</MudPaper>
</MudStack>

@code
{
    private string? _imageBase64;

    private async Task UploadFiles(IBrowserFile file)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"size:{file.Size}");
        await using var openReadStream = file.OpenReadStream(file.Size);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[file.Size];
        var readAsync = await openReadStream.ReadAsync(buffer);
        _imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer, 0, readAsync);
    }
}
```

Whenever I upload an image, the memory increases and the garbage collector (GC) does not reclaim the excess memory. This continues until the page eventually crashes
[image]
[image]

I am trying to eliminate other possible causes, and I have found that when I comment out `Src="@string.Concat("data:image/png;base64,", _imageBase64)"`, the memory leak no longer occurs. This suggests that the image display is causing the memory leak.

To eliminate the possibility of the issue being related to MudBlazor, I directly used the HTML  tag, but the memory leak still occurred:

```html
           @*  <MudImage Height="400" Alt="pic" Class="rounded-lg" 
                      Src="@string.Concat("data:image/png;base64,", _imageBase64)" 
            /> *@

            <img src="@string.Concat("data:image/png;base64,", _imageBase64)" class="rounded-lg" height="400px"/>
```

In the end, I resolved the issue by using a JavaScript object URL.

However, I am still curious to know how this memory leak occurred. I wonder if there is a problem with my usage or if there is a potential bug in Blazor. I searched for similar issues but couldn't find anyone else experiencing the same problem.

Comment: This should be due to the fact that when using Base 64 images, we need to decode and render Base 64 images, which will increase memory consumption.